# How to show a ng-template?

Tags: angular

I defined some `ng-template`s to use in my Angular component:

```html
<ng-template #myTemplate>
  ... contents ...
</ng-template>
```

How can I show this template without using `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 1):

The directive to use is [`NgTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet):

```html
<template *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></template>
```

or

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```